# Is there any feature in css or bootstrap to increase the visibility of a radio button in IE 8?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

[image: Radio button visibility]

The radio button visibility is very less in IE 8 but it is good in Chrome. I want to increase the visibility of the radio button. Does it involve using a different color? The button default styling is from bootsrap.min.css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *visibility*, since *visibility* in CSS controls whether the element is actually visible or not - not the tone, color or transparency.
If you want the element to be more prominent, I suggest you change the background color of them. You can have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) to figure out what color to use. Then they'll have the same color regardless of what browser you use.

Comment: Thanks Rasmus. The background color was a good help to improve the element visibility. I was generally referring to the visibility of an element as opposed to the visibility property of CSS

Answer (score 1):

See if this can help you:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhLrnaud/)

```css
   input[type=radio] {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2, 2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2, 2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
    -o-transform: scale(2, 2);
   }
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not help much. The background color is a valid fix as mentioned in another answer